# Loop JavaScript in Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

i'm following the Django code that dynamically generates cards according to my amount of variables i have in a bank. For each card it consumes data from an API through ajax code. However, my ajax code is not being called every loop. It is called only once. What I can do is wrong, because I need ajax to be called every loop of HTML.

```
{% block content %}
<div id="auto" class="row">
    {% for row in list %}
        {% if row.state == 1 %}
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <h5 class="card-header">{{row.description}} - Temperatura Atual (˚C)</h5>
                    <!--<img class="card-img-top" src="{% static 'img/gauge.png' %}" width="100" height="200" alt="Card image cap">!-->
                    <canvas id="myChart-{{ forloop.counter }}" class="piechart"></canvas>
                    <script>
                            var rowId = {{ row.id }}
                            console.log(rowId);
                            readTempDinamic(rowId);
                            //refresh();
                    </script>
                    <p class="text-center font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 0.7rem"><span id="datetime"></span></p>
                    <a href="{% url 'row_details' pk=row.pk %}" class="btn botao-detalhar btn-sm">Show</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}


function readTempDinamic(rowId) {
    var endpointTemp = '/api/weatherData/getSensor/1/' + rowId + '/'
    console.log(endpointTemp);

    /* ############################################################################# */
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpointTemp,
        success: function(data){
            var row = []
            var value = []
            var read_data = []
            row = data.row
            value = data.value
            read_data = data.read_date

            generateGaugeCharts(row[0], read_data[0], value[0])
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
    /* ############################################################################# */
}
```

Comment: it seems like you are calling the function only when `{% if row.state == 1 %}` so only if you have entries in db that match this condition it would execute.

Comment: another thing that I noticed is you JS code is not inside the `<script>` tag, it could be because of that.